# Please remove link to irrelevant answer

Tags: support

On my recent question [regarding a Unity accessibility feature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402315/how-to-add-a-keyboard-modifier-state-applet-to-uniy-panel) some folks who did not read the question jumped at the chance to mark it as a dupe. Now the question is vandalized with an irrelevant "This question may already have an answer here" banner which distracts knowledgeable users from reading any further.

**Please remove the link banner to the irrelevant question.**

Thank you.

**Here is the banner is question:**
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry about it. That banner is only be visible to you (the OP of the question) until the question gets actually closed as a duplicate. Only once the question gets closed as a duplicate does the banner gets displayed by default to all the viewers of the question.

You have made your point very well by the way of clarification edit to your question and I agree that it is not a duplicate and I am hopeful that other community members would agree as well and won't vote to close the question.

Close votes already cast would disappear as time goes by and the duplicate banner that you are seeing would disappear as well when there are no more close votes left on that question.

Comment: I still have a lot to learn. How long has this been around?

Comment: @minerz029: At least since I have been a member of Ask Ubuntu... To go beyond that, we would have to search [metase] :-)

Comment: Hmm. So this was around before I was... Interesting, I guess I never posted a dupe question and so wouldn't know. Might look around [metase] a bit.

Comment: Thank you Aditya. So long as the banner is only visible to me, then it is not a hindrance to a proper answer. Thank you for mentioning that!

Answer (score 0):

Viewing your question, it actually isn't closed as a duplicate so there's no duplicate banner.

The question linked was [How to add a keyboard modifier state applet to Unity panel?](https://askubuntu.com/q/402315/176889)

---

This:

> [image]

is **not** a duplicate banner. It is a [*comment*](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment), which was written by xangua.

For future reference, an actual duplicate banner can be seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7) (and in *many* more questions). It is located under the question title and usually in yellow text.

Comment: The banner doesn't say "dupe" but it does suggest that the OP (me) already can find an answer to his question (which I can't). That will discourage knowledgeable readers from continuing any further.

Comment: @dotancohen See my edit. basically, that is a comment, not a duplicate banner.

Comment: See my edit to the question. I am not referring to xangua's comment, I am referring to the large banner that appears before the question.